# Firebase throws 403 "Permission denied" randomly on some files (iOS/Swift)

Tags: ios, firebase-storage, http-status-code-403

I have a pretty basic iOS/Swift app that uploads video files to firebase. Although I have found other posts on 403 errors, they all seemed to be systemic permissions issues.

I am posting *this* thread because 99% of the time the file uploads and gets permissions as expected. I have no fancy (or any) permission settings in the app or firebase, yet, occasionally a file returns 403.

Just to make sure I wasn't chasing my tail, I changed my rules (based on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/oXyspJwlgU0) to full permissions "true". Still get 403 for that specific file.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

I have a hunch, ***maybe*** something goes wrong when a file isn't uploaded all the way. Somehow it gets corrupt, but throws a 403 instead? (Stabbing in the dark of course).

Any ideas or similar issues out there?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you solved this problem but I want to share what I found while trying to solve a similar case.

I am writing a hybrid app that uses Firebase Storage to upload and download files. For test purposes I was not using authentication and everything was working fine. Then I implemented authentication, database rules and storage rules and everything worked well with database but not with Storage. 
With the storage rules:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/....myBucket.../o {
    match /{allPaths=**}  {
       allow read, write: if request.auth != null 
    }
  }
}
```

I always received 403 "permission denied" messages in response to the getDownloadURL() function, the files never loaded. I tried anonymous and email/password authentication, nothing happended. Then I tried some variations on the rules, but in the best case I received random 403 "permission denied" messages, sometimes a file would be loaded, sometimes not.

I finally solved the problem. I was using AngularFire's functions for authentication: $firebaseAuth(), $authAnonymously() and $authWithPassword(), but for Storage I was using the standard firebase.storage() function. Then, I changed Auth to standard functions: firebase.auth(), signInAnonymously() and signInWithEmailAndPassword(), and all the uploads and downloads started to work right.

Hope this helps somebody.